# React JS filter in Polyline google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-polyline, google-poly

i working in small project that use google map 90%
so in google map i would like to do a lot of polyline and filter on it .

that the issue im  try to figer it right now  .

any idea to help please
i dev with JS

Comment: Can you provide your detailed use case and an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of what you made so far? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).